# Netcat auto reconnect on disconnection

Tags: python, linux, bash, netcat

I've set up a series of netcat connections in a Bash/Debian Linux environment to remote servers which periodically send me messages. I'm continuously writing the results of these messages to a local file as so:

```
nc 192.168.1.38 23 >> results
nc 192.168.1.39 4501 >> results
nc 192.168.1.40 8080 >> results
```

Everything works great. But periodically, one of the remote servers kills the netcat connection (i.e. performance reasons, overloading, etc.). When this happens I have to manually reconnect to the server. Is there an automated method of immediately reconnecting, so that no intermediary messages are lost?

Suggestions in bash or python preferred.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an infnite loop.
When netcat ends it'll just start again... Infinitely...

Try this (bash script)

```
while true
do
    nc 192.168.1.38 23 >> results
    nc 192.168.1.39 4501 >> results
    nc 192.168.1.40 8080 >> results
done
```

Comment: Thanks. This appears to be the logical solution. For whatever reason however the netcat connection still dies, although this particular process runs indefinitely. I'm marking this answer as the solution as the issue seems to be related to the server I'm connecting to, and not the client.

Comment: That will run the netcats one by one, sequentally, not in parallel, only one at a time. Furthermore, if any of those single connections dies it won't be up again until the others are started and die too. This answer is just plain wrong. The loop part is ok, i'ts a loop, but it doesn't do what op is asking for in the context of multiple connections.