# Netcat should auto reconnect on disconnection

Tags: connection, netcat

I have a problem with network interruptions causing netcat to disconnect and then I have to rerun the script.

(/usr/bin/php < dummyInput.txt textGen.php | /usr/bin/nc 192.168.3.4 2001 >/dev/null &)

How can I make the above reconnect and continue after the network connection is broken and netcat exits?

This question [Netcat auto reconnect on disconnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34101933/netcat-auto-reconnect-on-disconnection) is similar but is not really answered.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
while [ 1 ]; do php < dummyInput.txt textGen.php | nc 192.168.3.4 2001 >/dev/null; sleep 5; done &
```

I added sleep 5 to slow down re-connection attempts. Set that to the number of seconds that makes sense for your situation.